# Grunt concat AngularJS files in the wrong order

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

This is the first time I use grunt, so I'm not sure if such thing can be done.

I have too many js files to write, and I don't wanna add one by one.

Most modules has a js folder, and in that folder (Alphabetically)

1. name.controller.js
2. name.module.js
3. name.service.js

For the concat task, I wrote:

```
src: ['app/**/*.js'],
dest: 'dist/app.js'
```

A problem occurs, because the controller is loaded before the module, that when I use: `angular.module('name').controller...` It does not recognize the module 'name'.

Are there rules I can give the concat task to know in which order to concat the files?

Or, is there a way to tell the controllers to wait until the module is loaded, and then load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to load the modules before the controllers and services, you can define that like this:

```
src: [
    'app/**/*.module.js',
    'app/**/*.controller.js',
    'app/**/*.services.js'],
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I used this, and added 'app/**/*.js', because not all files are these (there are factories, directives, w/e)

Comment: You're welcome. You should look into ES6 with babelify as well with import and export. It compiles your file into ES5 with the dependencies in the correct order. :-)